# Does Microsoft Graph support Skype?

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, skype-for-business

I would like to start a collaboration session from a web page.  I would like a document (excel, word are the most common) to be attached and invite several people to the session.  Is this possible using Microsoft Graph (current or near future)?

This is for an enterprise environment where all machines have Skype for Business running and possibly Office 365 SharePoint as well.

Thanks you,
Jason

Answer (score 3):

It does not support Skype as of January 2016.

The Graph and Skype teams are currently discussing how we can light up these scenarios, but we don't have anything to announce yet.

Comment: Agree, not available as of April 2016 as well.