# Create an online meeting/skype event with Microsoft Graph Api v1

Tags: api, microsoft-graph-api

I was wondering if anyone has had any success creating a skype event using microsoft graph api version 1.

Basically, by using the api, I want to send a skype event to a group.

I was looking at https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/beta/resources/event.md and I read that onlineMeetingUrl parameter is set when the organizer specifies an event as an online meeting.

But I could not find anything in the documentation on how to set the an event as online: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0

Did you ever have a similar problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not still supported (as of December 2018). Answer from a similar post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34932620/does-microsoft-graph-support-skype

Comment: I just found out that Microsoft is moving towards Microsoft Teams Product. You can now use the beta api to create an online meeting using the Microsoft Graph Beta Api. More here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=cs